# How to access cached data in Spark Streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Kafka broker with JSON data from my IoT applications. I connect to this server from a Spark Streaming application in order to do some processing.

I'd like to save in memory (RAM) some specific fields of my json data which I believe I could achieve using `cache()` and `persist()` operators.

Next time when I receive a new JSON data in the Spark Streaming application, I check in memory (RAM) if there are fields in common that I can retrieve. And if yes, I do some simple computations and I finally update the values of fields I saved in memory (RAM).

Thus, I would like to know if what I previously descibed is possible. If yes, do I have to use cache() or persist() ? And How can I retrieve from memory my fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible with `cache` / `persist` which uses memory or disk for the data in Spark applications (not necessarily for Spark Streaming applications only -- it's a more general use of [caching in Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching)).

But...in Spark Streaming you've got special support for such use cases which are called **stateful computations**. See [Spark Streaming Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) to explore what's possible.

I think for your use case [mapWithState](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions@mapWithState[StateType,MappedType](spec:org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[K,V,StateType,MappedType])(implicitevidence$2:scala.reflect.ClassTag[StateType],implicitevidence$3:scala.reflect.ClassTag[MappedType]):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MapWithStateDStream[K,V,StateType,MappedType]) operator is exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not work that way. Please think it through in a distributed way.

For the first part of keeping in RAM. You can use `cache()` or `persist()` anyone as by default they keep data in memory, of the worker.

You can verify this from **Apache Spark Code**.

```
 /** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (`MEMORY_ONLY`). */
  def persist(): this.type = persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

  /** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (`MEMORY_ONLY`). */
  def cache(): this.type = persist()
```

As far as I understand your use case, you need the UpdateStateByKey Operation to implement your second use case !

For more on Windowing see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#updatestatebykey-operation).